# pyhs2 set queue in query

Tags: python, hive, queue

I am using pyhs2 to query hive through python but I cannot set the queue inside the query.

I want to set the queue to adhoc

```
cursor.execute("set mapred.job.queue.name=adhoc;")
cursor.execute("select * from test")
pyhs2.error.Pyhs2Exception: 'Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask'
```

and when I try to put the queue inside the query:

```
cursor.execute("set mapred.job.queue.name=adhoc; select * from test")
```

The second part of the query doesn't get executed

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is not possible to run multiple statements with `pyhs2` therefore you are unable to set the mapred queue name. Pyhs2 is no longer maintained and the readme advises to use [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive) which supports these kind of operations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe What Angelo says is not really true.
You can set it in different context like this.

```
conn = pyhs2.connect(...)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('set mapred.job.queue.name=adhoc')
c.close()
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from test")
r = c.fetchall()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

I hope you got the idea.